# Error Exception Undefined property: Spatie\Backup\Events\BackupHasFailed::$exception

Tags: laravel, database-backups

Hello today I'm trying to call `php artisan backup:run` inside button views but the code show error

```
ErrorException
Undefined property: Spatie\Backup\Events\BackupHasFailed::$exception
```

Here is my code in controller

```
Route::get('/backup', function () {        Artisan::call('backup:run');        return redirect('/payment')->with('success', 'backup data success');    })->name('backup');
```

My code in view

```
=>    <a href="{{ route('backup') }}">Backup Database</a>
```

btw im using library spatie/laravel-backup